# Move main site into subfolder (htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

Need to organize several sites in one hosting account, putting each into its own folder.

Via CPANEL, this is completed and working for the add-on domains, but the main site (with all its subfolders) also needs to be in its own folder.

I have been doing this via PHP:

**example.com/index.php :**

```
<?php
    header('Location: subdir/mainsite/index.php');
?>
```

The down side is that there is a page flash as the site redirects.

Another downside is that the URL reflects the new location in the address bar:

```
http://example.com/subdir/mainsite/
```

I just want visitors to see `http://example.com`

I suspect this can be resolved by using htaccess instead of PHP.

So, if my domain is:

```
http://example.com
```

And I place the main site files in:

```
public_html/_sub/mainsite
```

And the add-on sites must continue to work...

What would the htaccess look like?

This is what I have thus far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_sub/mainsite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_sub/mainsite/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ _sub/mainsite/index.php [L]
```

Comment: What's the difference between this domain and any of the others that you solved?

Comment: Are you using Apache? Why not Virtual Hosts?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang I know next to nothing about Virtual Hosts. I am using a standard hosting company with CPANEL / Linux / (apache, I suppose), but I don't see anything in CPANEL about virtual hosts. Is this a possibility for me?

Comment: Blech, cPanel. ;) You're probably using Apache, in which case, Virtual Hosts would be your best option: they allow you to host multiple sites - each existing on different domains - on a single server. They're super awesome, and fairly simple to grasp (IMO).

Comment: @JoaquínO The difference is that the others were configured using CPANEL magic. That is, CPANEL has an `Add On Domains` area where I entered each domain name and the folder associated with that domain, and CPANEL made it all work without leaving behind any `.htaccess files`. So this one I must do myself.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Yeah, that's where I'm at: living in CPANEL world on a typical shared hosting situation. So unless CPANEL / shared hosting allows it somehow, it's not poss. `Virtual Hosts` might be how it's done on the back end, but the question is whether I, as a low-end client, have access to that myself. Thus far, I haven't seen the term `virtual hosts` in the CPANEL icon menus. Unless I have missed it... ?

Comment: @crashwap Do you have access to your server via SSH? That would be the easiest way to get at the necessary config files.

Comment: No, we shared hosting types are the [untouchable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caste_system_in_India) caste of the LAMP stack. No shell access, whether secure or not. I would need to upgrade to a VPS, which would be ~ 12x more expensive, which is not poss. at the moment.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like shit.. I really suggest to search in your hosting help section.. Or trying to contact anyone of the help desk.. Not really a big cPanel fan here.. If you try the .htaccess thing, you probably will get some weird non-secure, cross-site overlapping with the other sites (since they will be in a main site's subdirectory)

Comment: What I mean is, what would happen if I type into my browser something like www.yourmaindomain.com/_sub/yourothersite?

Comment: @JoaquínO It remains with the longer path displayed. However, even sub-pages are displayed properly if accessed via the domain only: `http://yourothersite/nutherpage.php` -- but if accessed via the longer path, the longer path stays: `http://yourmaindomain.com/_sub/yourothersite/nutherpage.php`.  *CPANEL magic* that I wish to duplicate.

Comment: Don't you think it's ugly to be able to access site B via a subdirectory of site A? You shouldn't have any site inside other site..